# Getting full name of a file when copying using a wildcard

Tags: svn, batch-file

I have a batch file in which I am using `xcopy` to move some files around. The issue is that in using `xcopy` I'm using a wildcard because I don't know the file extension but I know the file name. However, I need to know the full file name in order to do the very next command, in this case add it to svn.

Here is what this snippet of the batch currently looks like:

```
xcopy /q /y C:\path\to\file\image.* D:\svn\folder
svn add D:\svn\folder\image.???   <-- not sure what to do here
```

I've thought about using the `/f` flag for `xcopy` but that would produce the source **and** destination path and I only need the file name. Plus I would have to do the command again by putting it in a `FOR` just to put it in a variable, assuming I can get the file name out of that command.

What are my options here? How do I get the full file name when using wildcards so I can add this file to svn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a for loop that iterates only over the file you're interested in.

```
FOR %%F in ("C:\path\to\file\image.*") do (
    xcopy /q /y %%F D:\svn\folder
    svn add D:\svn\folder\%%~nxF
)
```

Inside the loop, you can refer to the full path name of the file using the iteration variable itself (`%%F` in my example). To refer to the bare file name with extension, you insert `~nx` before the variable name (`%%~nxF`).

Another option is getting the file name and extension in a variable:

```
FOR %%F in ("C:\path\to\file\image.*") do set FILENAME=%%~nxF
xcopy /q /y C:\path\to\file\%FILENAME% D:\svn\folder
svn add D:\svn\folder\%FILENAME%
```

With this approach you have to repeat the directory name `C:\path\to\file\` in your code or put it in another variable and reuse it.